# IOS App rejected: 2.23 - Apps must follow the iOS Data Storage Guidelines

Tags: iphone, swift, ios9.3

I submitted my first app sometime back but it got rejected due to IOS Data Storage Guideline thing.

I researched a lot and found that Document Directory should have only user specific data else it should be marked as do not backup. I followed below steps and found that only 0.2kb data is backed up by my app.
- Install and launch your app
    - Go to Settings > iCloud > Storage > Manage Storage
    - Select your device
    - If necessary, tap "Show all apps"
    - Check your app's storage

What i want to know is that even though my Document and tmp directory are empty from where i'm getting this 0.2kb  data.

[screenshot of my app directory from xcode](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VVa1U.png)

Any suggestions?

Comment: You need to specify if you're using swift or objectiveC, even if your code is already in swift so others will easily see your post...

Comment: @0yeoj i'm using swift.

Comment: i believe you need `NSFileManager` for this, try to look [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25100262/save-data-to-plist-file-in-swift)..

Comment: @0yeoj i think this explains my issue. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24643919/rejection-2-23-apps-must-follow-the-ios-data-storage-guidelines-we-do-not-h

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure this solves your entire problem, but you cannot modify files inside your bundle. The `setResource` call on something inside your bundle is causing an error. I don't understand why you would call it on something that is part of your application.

Comment: I thought that it maybe the csv file that is getting backed up because if you see the screenshot that i have attached, Documents and tmp folders are empty and on checking the app storage on iCloud my device is showing 0.7Kb. So my problem is from where is this 0.7Kb data is coming if cache is not backed up by iTunes.